# Why is long long value not printed correctly?

Tags: c++, printf, long-integer

Why is the long long value not printed as I expect in the following code snippet?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 1363177921;
    long long unsigned y = x * 1000000;
    printf("y: %llu\n", y); // Why is 1363177921000000 not printed?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could have isolated the calculation and the printing by adding the line "assert(y == 1363177921000000);" (which would have failed) before the printf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the printing that's at fault. You have integer overflow in:

```
long long unsigned y = x * 1000000;
```

Change that to:

```
long long unsigned y = x * 1000000ull;
```

Answer (score 4):

Because your `x` is not a `long long`, nor is `1000000` - it is only converted to `long long` AFTER the multiplication.

Make it `1000000ULL`, and you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that x is int  and 1000000 will be long. Now the compiler will multiply them as it was multiplying 2 long and then the result is converted to long long

To solve add an implicit typecasting before x or 100000 or convert x into long long  as show below

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
         int x = 1363177921;
         long long unsigned y = (long long )x * 1000000;
         printf("y: %llu\n", y); // Why is 1363177921000000 not printed?
         return 0;
 }
```

http://codepad.org/rLW8fGTA